# what does opcode FF350E204000 do?

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode

I've got the 32bit opcode: `FF 35 0E 20 40 00`. Does anybody know a good OpCode table that gives an answer to this? (I know I could use a disassembler, but I'd like to know, how to determine this with an opcode table). I found [this](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder.html) webpage, but there are 7 different solutions for `FF`. I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place. You should looking this in Intel's or AMD's official documentation.

`Appendix A Opcode Map` of `Vol 2B` of `Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 3A and 3B` says that `FF` is `INC/DEC Grp5`<sup>`1A`</sup>.

`Table A-6 Opcode Extensions for One- and Two-byte Opcodes by Group Number` of `Vol 2B` says `FF`/`Group 5` either of `INC`, `DEC`, `CALLN`, `CALLF`, `JMPN`, `JMPF`, `PUSH`, depending on bits 5 through 3 of the `ModR/M` byte, the byte that follows. (0x35>>3)&7=6 or 110 in binary. So, this is `PUSH Ev`.

`Chapter 2 Instruction Format` of `Vol 2A` explains what parts an instruction consists of, including those `ModR/M` bytes and what not.

`Appendix A Using Opcode Tables` of `Vol 2B` tells you for `E`:

> A ModR/M byte follows the opcode and specifies the operand. The operand is either a general-purpose register or a memory address. If it is a memory address, the address is computed from a segment register and any of the following values: a base register, an index register, a scaling factor, a displacement.

It also tells you for `v`:

> Word, doubleword or quadword (in 64-bit mode), depending on operand-size attribute.

So, you know that `Ev` means a register or a memory operand and since this is for 32-bit code and there are no instruction prefixes, the operand size is 32 bits. So, `Ev` a 32-bit register or a 32-bit variable in memory.

Now you need to figure out the rest of the bytes from ModR/M until the end.

Look at `Figure 2-1. Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Instruction Format` of `Vol 2A`. It tells you that in `ModR/M`=0x35:

`Mod` = 00 (binary)
`Reg` = 110 (binary; we've extracted these 3 bits before)
`R/M` = 101 (binary)

`Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte` of `Vol 2A` tells you that `Mod` = 00 and `R/M` = 101 means `disp32`, IOW, there's a memory operand consisting of a 32-bit displacement in the instruction.

The `Reg` field of the `ModR/M` byte has already been used to choose one of the seven instructions and therefore this field does not encode a register operand.

So, your instruction is `PUSH DWORD [0x0040200E]`.

And that agrees with my disassembler output.

Comment: Table A-6 Opcode Extensions for One- and Two-byte Opcodes by Group Number is inside Vol 2D (Order Number: 334569-068), not Vol 2B.

Answer (score 18):

Let's try going through this byte sequence one byte at a time.

1. The first byte is `FF`. Looking it up in the Opcode Map in the Intel Instruction Set Reference tells us that this is an `INC` or a `DEC` instruction, along with the cryptical "Grp 5 - 1A". The 1A means that "Bits 5, 4, and 3 of ModR/M byte used as an opcode extension". The ModR/M byte is the byte that encodes the source and the address of the operands that are used for this instruction. In this case, the three bits are used for extending the opcode.
2. The next byte is `35`. This is the ModR/M byte, which normally appears right after the opcode itself, in instructions that use it. `35` (in hex) is `00110101` in binary, so bits 5, 4, and 3 are `110`. Looking this up in the opcode extension table (Table A-6) we can see that this means this is a `PUSH d64 Ev` instruction. The `d64` footnote means that "When in 64-bit mode, instruction defaults to 64-bit operand size and cannot encode 32-bit operand size.". This is expected for the `PUSH` instruction. `Ev` is a symbol that specifies the operand encoding - most importantly, it states that a ModR/M byte follows the opcode itself.  The `v`, on the other hand, signals that the operand's size is dependent on the operand-size attribute. We already have the ModR/M byte, so let's decode it (Table 2-2, assuming that this code is running in 32-bit mode) : the effective address is specified by a `disp32`, which means that a 32-bit displacement should follow the ModR/M byte. The part specifying the register says that `ESI` should be used, but in this case this field is used for the opcode extension, so it isn't used to signify a register source operand.
3. The next four bytes are the 32-bit displacement. `0E 20 40 00`, when decoded as little endian, means `0x40200e`. This is the address of the operand that will be used for this instruction.

Summing it all up, we got that `FF 35 0E 20 40 00` is `PUSH DWORD [0x40200e]`, i.e. it will push the 32-bit value read from the address `0x40200e` on the stack.