# Why call instruction opcode is represented as FF15?

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode

I am still learning assembly and trying to connect an instruction with it's opcode. Reading pdf at
https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE101?show=content

It just dissect a PE file of a simple program that show message box in windows, the code is "removing all unrelated entries"

```
push 0
push Title + DATADELTA
push Caption + DATADELTA
push 0
call [__imp__MessageBoxA]
```

When trying to look at the generated exe file ".text" section, the last call is represent with opcode "FF15" checking Intel manual also opcode list here http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

You will find the "call" instruction opcode as just "FF", then what "15" refer to or came from?

Comment: I don't think you are reading the chart correctly. Call shares the FF with several other instructions. The second byte selects the instruction and adressing mode.

Comment: It's actually `FF /2` and the `/2`, together with the addressing mode, gives you the `15`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [what does opcode FF350E204000 do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209993/what-does-opcode-ff350e204000-do?rq=1)

It explains that an entire group of instructions starts with FF: `INC`, `DEC`, `CALLN`, `CALLF`, `JMPN`, `JMPF`, `PUSH`.

The instruction is determined by looking at bits 5 through 3 of the ModR/M byte (see e.g. [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#ModR.2FM) if you want to avoid the official intel manual), that is in your case, `0x15` (the byte that follows the `FF`).

The `0x15` is `0001 0101` in binary and the bits 5-3 are: `010` (the most left bit is by no. 7 and the most right bit is bit no 0, think of it as an array).

`010` in binary is 2 in which means you have to choose the third element from the list (INC is elem no 0) [INC, DEC, CALLN, CALLF, JMPN, JMPF, PUSH].

This gives you "CALLN".

So you know your `FF 15` is a `CALLN` instruction. N stands for near (as opposed to F / FAR)

Comment: Thanks for clarification, also to add to your answer from what I learned in the referenced question. Here R/M = 101 in binary which mean "disp32", ie: a memory operand consisting of 32bit displacement. That comes from table 2-2 in Intel instruction set reference manual.